# Getting picture from foursquare API

Tags: foursquare

The new update on from the foursquare API indicates to assemble a resolvable photo URL, take prefix + size + suffix, e.g.

```
 https://irs0.4sqi.net/img/general/300x500/2341723_vt1Kr-SfmRmdge-M7b4KNgX2_PHElyVbYL65pMnxEQw.jpg.
```

Here a sample of the response venue that I m getting but my link concatenation isn't working. How can i fix this issue ?
          https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/conveniencestore_100x100.png

```
    "response":{  
    "venues":[  
     {  
        "id":"5274eb0f498efd84c1aa5283",
        "name":"Starbucks",
        "contact":{  
           "phone":"3056532071",
           "formattedPhone":"(305) 653-2071",
           "twitter":"starbucks",
           "facebook":"22092443056",
           "facebookUsername":"Starbucks",
           "facebookName":"Starbucks"
        },
        "location":{  
           "address":"199 NE 167th Street",
           "crossStreet":"NE 2nd Ave.",
           "lat":25.928553,
           "lng":-80.19656,
           "labeledLatLngs":[  
              {  
                 "label":"display",
                 "lat":25.928553,
                 "lng":-80.19656
              }
           ],
           "distance":206,
           "postalCode":"33162",
           "cc":"US",
           "city":"Miami",
           "state":"FL",
           "country":"United States",
           "formattedAddress":[  
              "199 NE 167th Street (NE 2nd Ave.)",
              "Miami, FL 33162",
              "United States"
           ]
        },
        "categories":[  
           {  
              "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735",
              "name":"Coffee Shop",
              "pluralName":"Coffee Shops",
              "shortName":"Coffee Shop",
              "icon":{  
                 "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/coffeeshop_",
                 "suffix":".png"
              },
              "primary":true
           }
        ],
        "verified":true,
        "stats":{  
           "checkinsCount":614,
           "usersCount":196,
           "tipCount":7
        },
        "url":"http://www.starbucks.com",
        "allowMenuUrlEdit":true,
        "beenHere":{  
           "lastCheckinExpiredAt":0
        },
        "specials":{  
           "count":0,
           "items":[  

           ]
        },
        "storeId":"19899",
        "hereNow":{  
           "count":0,
           "summary":"Nobody here",
           "groups":[  

           ]
        },
        "referralId":"v-1486970551",
        "venueChains":[  
           {  
              "id":"556f676fbd6a75a99038d8ec"
           }
        ],
        "hasPerk":false
     },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of category icon, 32, 44, 64, and 88 are available.

ref. https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/category.html

e.g. https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/conveniencestore_32.png